# some random api discord.js node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня есть код:

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js') // подключение discord.js к файлу
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
    const res = fetch("https://some-random-api.ml/img/dog")
    .then(res => res.json())
   console.log(res);
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle('Lol')
    .setImage(res.link)
  message.channel.send(embed);
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'fox' // название команды
}
```

Он должен выводить рандомную картинку собачки, но не выводит, остаётся только заголовок
В консоль выводит Promise {  }

Answer (score 0):

Потому как в строке `console.log(res)`, и есть неразрешенный `Promise`.
Далее ты используешь этот самый неразрешенный `.setImage(res<Promise>.link)`.

Не знаю API Discord, но очевидно надо использовать асинхронные функции или запихнуть часть кода в `.then(res => res.json())`

```js
module.exports.run = /* ВОТ ЭТО */ async (client, message, args) => {
  const res = /* И ВОТ ЭТО */  (await fetch("https://some-random-api.ml/img/dog")).json()
  // теперь нам доступен объект 
  // res:{"link":"https://i.some-random-api.ml/GgVmK0NYuF.jpg"}
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle('Lol')
    .setImage(res.link)
  message.channel.send(embed)
}
```